# Is the partial derivative of this function continuous in $D=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2<1\}$?

Tags: calculus

> $f(x,y)=x+|y|^{1.5}sin(\frac{1}{y})$ when $y\neq0$
>
> $f(x,y)=0$ when $y=0$

is $f_x$ (partial derivative) continuous in $D=\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2<1\}$?

I am asking this because I had an exam where I said it is not continuous, because in my opinion $f_x=0$ for points on $y=0$, and $f_x=1$ for the rest of the points, which gives a non continuous function.

However this was marked as wrong, what am I missing?

Comment: I think you are right. I don 't understand why your answer was marked wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You were most likely marked down because of the reason you gave. A function is not continuous, *not because it assumes different values at different points.* A function is said to be discontinuous at a point of its domain if at least one of the following happens:

(1) the limit does not exist at that point,

(2) the limit exists but is different from the value of the function there.

Perhaps you got $f_x$ confused with $f.$ The question was about the continuity of $f_x,$ not $f.$

Comment: This was a question where an explanation was not required.